# Pass interface A to B losing attributes

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have two interfaces, `A` and `B`:

```js
Interface A { x: any, y: any }
Interface B { x: any }
```

If I do:

```js
const a: A = { x: 1, y: 1 }
const b: B = A;
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

The result is the same, `a` and `b` have the same value. I've tried:

```js
const b: B = A as B;
```

But the result is the same.

I want to do `B = A` and only keep common attributes. How could I do this without mapping all the attributes?

Comment: You are assigning the value of `A` to `B` in the first example. This would set the memory address of `B` to `A`. You are not clone/casting the value.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl yes, but in the second example I did it no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your capitalization is wrong. Try the following:

```
interface A { x: any, y: any }
interface B { x: any }

const a: A = { x: 1, y: 1 }
const b: B = a as B;

console.log(a);  // { "x": 1, "y": 1 }
console.log(b);  // { "x": 1, "y": 1 }
```

The interface is simply a contract. You must have, *a minimum of*, all the properties. You may however have more. See this example of the interfaces being used in a class.

```
interface A { x: any }
interface B { x: any, y: any }

class C implements A {
    x: any;
    constructor(x: any) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    serialize():object {
        return { x: this.x };
    }
}

class D extends C implements B {
    y: any;
    constructor(x: any, y: any) {
        super(x);
        this.y = y;
    }
    serialize():object {
        return Object.assign(super.serialize(), { y: this.y });
    }
}

const d: D = new D(1, 1);
const c: C = d as C;

console.log(c.serialize());  // { "x": 1, "y": 1 } NOT { "x": 1 }
console.log(d.serialize());  // { "x": 1, "y": 1 }
```

Even when I down-cast `d` to type `C` e.g. `c`, `c` still has the `y` property.

You would have to create a static clone method of some sort to take `A` and produce `C`.

```
class C implements A {
    static clone(a:A):C {
        return new C(a.x);
    }
}

const d: D = new D(1, 1);
const c: C = C.clone(d);

console.log(c.serialize()); // { "x": 1 }
console.log(d.serialize()); // { "x": 1, "y": 1 }
```

---

Unfortunately you need to know all the properties ahead of time. Using `as` just treats the object as an ancestor, but all the original properties remain intact.

```
interface Point2D<T> { x: T, y: T }
interface Point3D<T> extends Point2D<T> { z: T }

let p1: Point3D<Number> = { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 };
let p2: Point2D<Number> = p1 as Point2D<Number>;
let p3: Point2D<Number> = { x: p1.x, y: p1.y };

console.log(p1);  // { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 }
console.log(p2);  // { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 }
console.log(p3);  // { x: 0, y: 0 }
```